# Android - How to crop a Bitmap image not using getResources

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crop

I know how to crop a bitmap image from resources, but i want to cache image from ImageView to Bitmap, and then i want to crop it.

So, here is my code:

```
 mImageViewArt.buildDrawingCache();
 Bitmap bmap = mImageViewArt.getDrawingCache(); // works good

 Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),bmap);  // Doesn't work(Cannot be aplied Int to Bitmap)

 Bitmap resizedbitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the `bmp` intermediate variable?

If you want to crop the image returned by `getDrawingCache()`, you should just pass it as the input to `Bitmap.createBitmap()`, i.e.

```
mImageViewArt.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = mImageViewArt.getDrawingCache();

Bitmap resizedbitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmap, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Comment: thank you a lot! works perfectly:) i'd voted, but i can't, you know)